# nodejs cheerio selecting child element inside an each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to select the `strong a` tags that's inside the .info class

```
$(".info").each(function(i, item){
    console.log($(this).children("strong a").text())
});
```

it's selecting the info class correctly, just not the `strong a`

[image]

Comment: There's a lot of .info's so that wouldn't work I don't think, I would have to loop the .info strong a @31piy

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
$(".info").each(function(i, item){
    console.log($("strong a", item).text())
});
```

Comment: @SkylarLopez `children` only considers the first level of children of that node. For what you were doing you should have used `find`, but i find this shorthand more cleaner

Comment: Thanks a lot for this man. You saved me

Answer (score 5):

Inside a loop, you can also use like this

```
$(".info").each(function(i, item){
   $(this).find("strong a").text();
});
```